# ElectronのTypescript+Webpackテンプレートが実行できない

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, electron

[Electron Forge](https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template)のページに従い、Electronのテンプレートを以下のコマンドを実行してインストールしました。

```
npx create-electron-app my-new-app --template=typescript-webpack
```

次に

```
npm run start
```

を実行すると、コマンドウィンドウに以下のようなエラーメッセージが表示されました。

```
 $ npm run start

> my-new-app@1.0.0 start
> electron-forge start

✔ Checking your system
✔ Locating Application

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Expected plugin to either be a plugin instance or a { name, config } object but found @electron-forge/plugin-webpack,[object Object]

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
```

ググってみましたが、同じエラーの問題が出た人はいませんでした。1週間前に作った別のプロジェクトにはエラーメッセージもなく使えていたので、そのプロジェクトをコピーして実行すると、普通に動きました。
しかし、次のコマンドを実行すると

```
npm audit
```

22 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 19 high)が出てきました。
エラーは

```
got  <11.8.5 
Severity: moderate
```

と

```
minimatch  <3.0.5
Severity: high
```

で、npm audit fix や npm audit fix --force でも直りませんでした。そこで、package.jsonとpackage-lock.jsonを書き換えることでこのエラーを修正しました。その後、node_modulesフォルダを削除して、npm installを実行。
しかし、

```
`npm run start`
```

を実行すると、また一番最初のエラーが発生しました。

electron-forge/plugin-webpackに問題があると思われますが、まだこの分野は勉強し始めたばかりでプラグインの設定？がよくわかりません。

ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

次のissueの事象かと思います(最近の変更により発生した不具合のようです):

- [Webpack template has not been updated to the new plugins syntax #2992](https://github.com/electron/forge/issues/2992)

[曰く](https://github.com/electron/forge/issues/2992#issuecomment-1293122256)、

> the fix has not been published yet, we're aiming to get that out tomorrow PST

とのことなので、しばらく待てば修正は反映されると思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！！